# Django replacing html content with context tags

Tags: html, django

I have a template which contains:

Example 1:

```
{% if player_mark %}
    {% if commun.intern > threshold %}
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"
           href="{% url 'games:map:town_map' map_id=map.id home_id=homecall.id %}"><i
                class="fa fa-phone-square fa-fw"></i>
             {{ title_header }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Example 1 Context:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['player_mark'] = True
    context['title_header'] = "This is map for home town"
    return context
```

This same statement is copy and pasted about 15 times and to make it tidier i'm looking into having one and it look like this

Example 2:

```
{% if {{ player_header }} %}
    {% if commun.intern > threshold %}
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"
           href="{% url '{{ url_header }}' map_id=map.id home_id=homecall.id %}"><i
                class="fa fa-phone-square fa-fw"></i>
             {{ title_header }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

then just updating it inside the context with what i need like so

Example 2 Context:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['player_header'] = ???
    context['url_header'] = ???
    context['title_header'] = "This is map for home town"
    )
    return context
```

I thought id be able to just replace the if statement in example one with contents of Example 2 but then i don't know how to structure this in the context_view.

Any ideas, need anything else let me know.

This is my attempt so far on the url context:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['url_header'] = 'games:map:town_map' + "?{}{}".format(
        map_id=self.map.id,  ----- Unsure if this is correct way to pass url varibales
        home_id=self)    ----- Unsure if this is correct way to pass url varibales

    context['header'] = "This is map for home town"
    return context
```

Hopefully this gives a better idea of what i'm talking about.

Solution HTML:

```
{% if button %}
    {% if commun.intern > threshold %}
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"
           href="{% url url_path map_id=map.id home_id=homecall.id %}"><i
                class="fa fa-phone-square fa-fw"></i>
            {{ header }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Solution Context:

```
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['button'] = True
    context['url_path'] = 'games:map:town_map'
    context['header'] = "This is map for home town"
    return context
```

How i got to solution, after some html reading i found that i was going wrong because of the brackets {{}} These are for printing {% %} are for using functions.

Comment: so, you're looking for a solution replacing the `???` in the code posted above?

Comment: Yes, if you require more information on the question i'm happy to try my best

Comment: You should edit the question to add the `def` being used for `example1` context

Comment: @SreetamDas updated with context and an attempt